# Update a View in a MVC Web Application from another View in another MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Survey presented in a Tablet based on a MVC Web Application where each answer is stored with the id of the employee that have presented the survey to be filled.

The original solution has a numeric keyboard where the employee inserts his PIN first to unlock the survey, and then present the Survey to the customer so it can answer it.

The problem I face in a new project, is that the employee don't have access to the Tablet to insert his PIN so he has to do it from his PC.

How can I send the Id to the View of the Survey in the Tablet from the Employee's PC that runs another MVC Web Application?

I have no idea how to create this kind of communication in .NET MVC.

Comment: There are many ways to share data among web applications. The best way is to use web api. But if you don't want to do that, you can share a common database where you will store the id from first application. Then from the second application you can retrieve that in the controller and get that value calling ajax from the view. I think you got some idea

Comment: Hi, thanks! Yes I have understand the idea. The employee clicks a button in his Web Application that stores his id in the database, something like "survey_employee_Id_lock". Then the survey reads this information to associate the answer with the employee.

Comment: I just gave you the idea. Now you have to implement that, which is a challenge for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the tip ;)